# Selection gender menu in registration user

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to add a section under username to ask what gender the user is and I would like to do it through a menu with 2 selections (male and female). How can I do? Edit: How can I save the choice the user made in RegisterActivity

RegisterActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // When register is clicked check if fields are empty and if password is longer than 6 characters and call register method
    btn_register.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String txt_username = username.getText().toString();
        String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
        String txt_password = password.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_password)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (txt_password.length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password must be at least 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            register(txt_username, txt_email, txt_password);
        }
    });
}

private void register(final String username, final String email, final String password) {
    // If register task is successful add a reference to Users
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("id", userid);
                    hashMap.put("username", username);  
                    hashMap.put("search", username.toLowerCase());
                    hashMap.put("address", "To be added");
                    hashMap.put("gender", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RadioGroup`

```
<RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

  <RadioButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Male"
     android:id="@+id/radioButton"
     android:checked="false"
     android:textSize="25dp" />

  <RadioButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Female"
     android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
     android:checked="false"
     android:textSize="25dp"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

For more check [official](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup)

Comment: How can I save the choice the user made in RegisterActivity? in java. Edited question

Comment: Thats a different question. Post another question for that

Comment: Done, Can you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230854/save-gender-selection-in-register-user